The set of the points where a measurable function is continuous is measurable
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue-measurable function and let $C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n | f \text{ is continuous in } x \}$. Show that $C$ is Lebesgue-measurable.
I found a proof which is quite long, however my professor said that there is a one-line (meaning: almost trivial) proof of this statement. What do you think it might be? Hausdorff measure might be relevant (however we just know the definition, not its propertisin details).

Perhaps ask your professor whether the simple proof makes use of Lebesgue measurability of the function, since I'm somewhat familiar with the result for an arbitrary function and I have no idea how knowing the function is Lebesgue measurable allows for a simpler proof.

The continuity set of a real-valued function is $G_{\delta}$ i.e., a countable intersection of open sets. Open sets are measurable. Countable intersections of measurable sets are measurable.

I see. Didn't know about this. Thank you very much.
